# What are my options to deal with this stale closure in React besides using ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the library React Datasheet Grid, the main component has a property called [OnActiveCellChange](https://react-datasheet-grid.netlify.app/docs/api-reference/props#onactivecellchange), to which i'm passing my custom function:

```
const [selectedCell, setSelectedCell] = useState([])
...
function handleCellSelection({ cell }) { 
   if(cell) {
     const {row, col} = cell;
     const newData = data[row][col]; 

     if(!newData.unpickable) {    
 
       console.log(selectedCell); // prints empty array

       setSelectedCell(selectedCell => [...selectedCell, newData.value]);
     }
   }
 }
...
<DataSheetGrid
   className={'overwriteDisabledStyles'}
   value={data}
   onChange={setData}
   columns={columns}
   onActiveCellChange={handleCellSelection}
   headerRowHeight={false}
   gutterColumn={false}
   lockRows
/>
```

The problem is that I wish to make some checks with the state variable "selectedCell", while I managed to update the state from with the functional form, I can't access the the state variable. I managed to use the variable using "useRef".

I want to know if I can tackle the problem in any other way.

EDIT:

Trying to clarify my question:

What I want is to, inside the `handleCellSelection` function, make some checks before inserting the newData using the `setSelectedCell`. Like searching the `selectedCell` array for existing values:

```
const valueAlreadyExists = selectedCell.some((existingCell) => {
   return existingCell === newData.value
});
```

Yet, when the `handleCellSelection` function is called, the value of `selectedCell` is always an empty array. It should be the values that are being inserted in the array. I know there are values there because when I console.log outside the `handleCellSelection` they appear correctly.

So, I managed to access them inside the `handleCellSelection` using `useRef()` but what I am searching for is another option to solve this.

Comment: Using a React ref to hold a cache of the current state and accessing it in callbacks is  the way to access the current state when the callback appears to be "memoized" or otherwise not updated by a child component after subsequent renders.

Comment: Hello @DrewReese, thanks for the comment. So using ref in this case is a "good" practice? Since the child component is in a external library, how would I make it update with the parent?

Comment: It's not a "bad" practice, it is just sort of how it is in these specific use cases. Can you clarify your second question? How would you make *what* update with the parent?

Comment: @Guilherme please add more information to your question - specifically:
1. what you're expecting to happen
2. what's actually happening

Comment: I agree. We may need a bit more context around what you are actually trying to do with the `selectedCell` state to make a more informed suggestion.

Comment: @DrewReese I meant update the `selectedCell` within the child component. @gear4 thanks for the heads up, just edited.

Comment: You can do that `valueAlreadyExists ` check in the `setSelectedCell` callback function where you have access to the current state value. Whether or not it is useful there depends on what you are trying to accomplish.